# Volley no Android

Tags: android

Volley no Android, pelo entendi ela é uma biblioteca, a dúvida é:

- Biblioteca para que?
- Ela é nativa do Android?
- Se sim, como utilizar? Se não onde baixar?

Comment: Alguém??????????

Comment: Se a dúvida foi esclarecida, por favor marque a resposta como correta.

Answer (score 4):

Bom, vamos por partes.

**O que é o Volley?**

O Volley é uma biblioteca do google para android, que tem por objetivo tornar a implementação de http mais "fácil e otimizada".

**Ele é nativo no android?**

Não, você precisa baixar a lib e adicionar ao arquivo build.gradle no projeto pra começar a utilizar.

Link: **'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'**

**Obs**: Embora quando tenha surgido, muita gente utilizou a lib para melhorar e tentar reduzir código para requisições http no android, que convenhamos era muito burocrático, hoje em dia existem opções melhores.

Posso te recomendar a lib **Retrofit**, que essa sua sim, sua implementação é muito mais simples e vejo muita gente utilizando, em todos os projetos que mantenho atualmente, migrei para o retrofit.

**Bônus**

**Bom, mas o que é o Retrofit ?**

O Retrofit é um framework desenvolvido pela Square, que tem por finalidade otimizar a comunicação http do android, mais especificamente, utilizando o padrão REST, que por Sinal, acabou virando um "padrão de mercado".

**Ele é Nativo no android ?**

Também não, mas para sua utilização basta adicionar a linha abaixo ao arquivo build.gradle:

'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'

Fontes: [Volley Android](https://felipenipo.wordpress.com/2014/10/17/http-em-android-com-volley/)

[Retrofit Android](http://www.devmedia.com.br/android-retrofit-primeiros-passos-com-a-retrofit-api/31857)